# Store a for loop in php variable

Tags: php, validation, loops, variables, if-statement

```
$minutes = for($i = 1; $i <= 60;$i++) {return $i.'||';};
if($input != $minutes) {
exucute code here;
}
```

I have this piece of code here because I want to validate my inputs to check if their values are from 1-60. How do I go about checking this without writing every single number out. Arrays will not work here because the same goes for a foreach loop; it cannot be stored as a variable.

Comment: Im confused what is wrong with `if (($input < 1) || ($input > 60))` or even the in array like @MateiMihai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I don't understand

> Arrays will not work here because the same goes for a foreach loop; it cannot be stored as a variable.

I would recommend you to use `in_array` and `range` functions:

```
if (!in_array($input, range(1, 60))) {
    // exec
}
```